# Converting a generic argument to an int in java, provided that it is a number

Tags: java, generics

Here's what I've been trying to do, in a nutshell:

```
class example <T extends Number>
{
    private int function(T number)
    {
        int x = (int) number;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to make it so that T is a number so I can convert it to an int inside that function. The problem is that I'm getting an "incovertible types" error, so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the abstract class `Number` is the superclass of classes
 * `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`,
 * `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`,
 * `Integer`, `Long`, and `Short`...

if you want to have an int representation, you should use the `.intValue()` function.

If that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, I don't think you need generics.  I think you can just:

```
private int func(Number n) {
  return n.intValue();
}
```

If you're trying to do something with generics, I'd take that out at the moment and get just the above working, first.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old. Just for practice purposes (not recommended in production), you can use the wrapper class Integer instead of primitive type int.

```
int x = (Integer) number;
```

The point is to convert a generic type to primitive type will throw an error, a wrapper class such as Number, BigInteger or Integer would be more valid.

Comment: This won't work in a lot of circumstances. What happens when a `BigInteger` is passed in?

Comment: You're right, thus I mentioned it should only be used for practice. My point was casting a Number to primitive type won't work, using a wrapper class such as BigInteger, or Integer, or Number makes more sense. Or as VonC mentioned, `Number.toIntValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
x=number.intValue();
```